Ios Build is not showing in the TestFlight
I have an IOS app build using Flutter and I am trying to upload to app store. While uploading to the TestFlight I am not getting any error and it showing like uploaded. But it not showing in the app store or TestFlight. I have tried many times the same issue is repeating.
I tried multiple times but same issue. Status I am getting uploaded.

Since the description is not detailed enough, I assumed that the sentense "...it showing like uploaded." in your question means that the log shows no error.
Under this circumstance, how do you check that "It not showing in the app store or TestFlight."? Did you check it by mobile's app store and testflight app, or the Apple's developer website (Apple developer)?
If you just check it by mobile's app store and testflight app, it is normal that you can not find your app since you may not be a tester of your app and , obviously, you have not published your app to appstore.
If you have check your developer website, than I probably need more details such as log to help you.
Hope this info could help you.

From xcode it showing uploaded but in the TestFlight the uploaded build is not showing and also I am not getting any error log also. I checked through developer account in the test flight session.

Open aapstoreconnect and there in testflight section select your build, check if there is any warning related encryption (appstore generally asks for "does your app use any encryption") -> select none and then good to go.
Select tester group or individual tester.
I hope this helps.

After uploading the build it does not show the developer console. In Xcode it is showing uploaded successfully.  for a few minutes only the version shows in developer console after that it will show no build.

@KrishnaaKrishna did you find a solution for it. Im facing similar issue.
